# Iterate through array for two elements

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I'm trying to make quite simple thing. Loop through array and get two elements in one iteration instead of one. Here is the code, maybe someone would point my mistakes :)

```
        for(int i = 0; i < temporary.size(); i = i + 2)
        {

            LayoutInflater inflater;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getParent().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.smartuilinear ,
                            null);
                Button ls1, ls2;
                ls1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.ls1);
                ls2 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.ls2);
                ls1.setText("i= "+i+ "info " + temporary.get(i).toString());
                int j = i + 1;
                ls2.setText("i= "+j+ "info " + temporary.get(j).toString());

            linear.addView(v);
        }
```

Edit: The problem when size is odd number. I do not wish to loose that last element. by decrementing value if size is odd.

---

Well i guess my question was not clear enough. The loop works, but how not to loose the last object in list, if the list size is not even? Obviously if the list size is not even on the last loop, j shouldn't be initialized. I hope this makes a little bit clear

Comment: What's the problem? Aside from the fact that `temporary` clearly isn't an array...

Comment: ....and whats the problem?

Comment: you should check that the array does not have an odd number of elements (odd - number that is not a multiple of 2)

Comment: The problem is I do not know how to make it work. Clearly the above code isn't right and it doesn't work, i posted it just to get the idea of what I am trying to do

Comment: Checking for odd number was an idea, but how not to loose the last element if number is odd ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever it is that is not working does not directly relate to the loop structure, assuming temporary is a List with an even number of elements. I wrote a simplified test program based on your code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String[] data = {"aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd"};
    List<String> temporary = new ArrayList<String>();
    temporary.addAll(Arrays.asList(data));
    for (int i = 0; i < temporary.size(); i = i + 2) {
      System.out.println("i= " + i + " first " + temporary.get(i).toString());
      int j = i + 1;
      System.out.println("i= " + j + " second " + temporary.get(j).toString());
    }
  }
}
```

It runs, with output:

```
i= 0 first aaa
i= 1 second bbb
i= 2 first ccc
i= 3 second ddd
```

You need to look at the rest of the code, not represented in my test program. With no clues as to the failure symptoms and the definitions of the rest of the variables it is not possible to diagnose the failure.

==============================================================================

Following clarification of the problem, here is a variation of the test program that handles either even or odd temporary sizes:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Odd length");
    test(new String[] { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee" });
    System.out.println("Even length");
    test(new String[] { "xxx", "yyy" });
    System.out.println("Empty");
    test(new String[] {});
  }

  private static void test(String[] data) {
    List<String> temporary = new ArrayList<String>();
    temporary.addAll(Arrays.asList(data));
    for (int i = 0; i < temporary.size(); i = i + 2) {
      System.out.println("i= " + i + " first " + temporary.get(i).toString());
      int j = i + 1;
      if (j < temporary.size()) {
        System.out
            .println("i= " + j + " second " + temporary.get(j).toString());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Odd length
i= 0 first aaa
i= 1 second bbb
i= 2 first ccc
i= 3 second ddd
i= 4 first eee
Even length
i= 0 first xxx
i= 1 second yyy
Empty
```

Comment: Well i guess my question was not clear enough. The loop works, but how not to loose the last object in list, if the list size is not even? Obviously if the list size is not even on the last loop, j shouldn't be initialized. I hope this makes a little bit clear

Comment: I've added a new test program that handles even or odd temporary sizes.

Comment: Patricia +1, because you deserve it :) (i do too LOL)

Answer (score 1):

There is possibility the above code may throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in the line

```
  ls2.setText("i= "+j+ "info " + temporary.get(j).toString());
```

since you check whether i < temporary.size() in for loop if the temporary List or Vector has odd number of value the above code will fail.

Answer (score 1):

It will fail at some point!

If I were you, I will look how to improve how I save my values in that list.

For example, you could have better something like

```
List<String[]> temporary = new ArrayList<String[]>();
temporary.add(new String[]{value1, value2});
```

Then:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < temporary.size(); i++)
    {

        LayoutInflater inflater;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getParent().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.smartuilinear ,
                        null);
            Button ls1, ls2;
            ls1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.ls1);
            ls2 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.ls2);
            String[] subValues = temporary.get(i);
            ls1.setText("info " + subValues[0]);
            ls2.setText("info 2" + subValues[1]);
        linear.addView(v);
    }
```

Comment: This would be best, yet, in my case its not quite possible to do with my list :(

Answer (score 0):

I find it simpler to just increment the index within the for loop body as opposed to try and track multiple variables and then "double increment" in the for loop declaration.

```
for(int i = 0, s=temporary.size(); i < s; **++i**)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getParent().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.smartuilinear,  null);
    Button ls1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.ls1);
    Button ls2 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.ls2);
    ls1.setText("i= "+i+ "info " + temporary.get(i).toString());
    **++i;**
    ls2.setText("i= "+i+ "info " + temporary.get(i).toString());
    linear.addView(v);
}
```